# How to pass data from textview to edit text using intent to another activity

Tags: android

I am using listview in adapter and i need to pass textviews of list view to edit text from one activity to  another activity to update the items, but when i click on item it stop the activity. I have all the items in textviews.

```
 ListView yourListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

// get data from the table by the ListAdapter

               MyAdapter myAdapter=new MyAdapter(all_users_data.this, allevent);
                yourListView .setAdapter(myAdapter);
                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {
                        TextView name = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
                        TextView time = view.findViewById(R.id.time);
                        TextView date = view.findViewById(R.id.date);
                        TextView type = view.findViewById(R.id.type);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(all_users_data.this,Singleitem.class);
                        intent.putExtra( "name", name.getText().toString());
                         intent.putExtra("time", time.getText().toString());
                        intent.putExtra("date", date.getText().toString());
                        intent.putExtra("type", type.getText().toString());
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
```

Activity two

```
package com.example.eventreminder;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Singleitem extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editname;
    EditText edittime;
    EditText editdate;
    EditText edittype;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_singleitem);
        editname = findViewById(R.id.name);
        edittime = findViewById(R.id.time);
        editdate = findViewById(R.id.date);
        edittype = findViewById(R.id.type);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
        String n1= getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
        editname.setText(n1);
        String t =  getIntent().getStringExtra("time");
        edittime.setText(t);
        String d=  getIntent().getStringExtra("date");
        editdate.setText(d);
        String t1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("type");
        edittype.setText(t1);
        // Receiving value into activity using intent.
      ;

        // Setting up received value into EditText.

    }
}
```

Anyone can help me please, Thank you.

Comment: Post the `Logcat` error logs...

Comment: What was the error shown in your log

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 ListView yourListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);


                        TextView name = findViewById(R.id.name);
                        TextView time = findViewById(R.id.time);
                        TextView date = findViewById(R.id.date);
                        TextView type = findViewById(R.id.type);


               MyAdapter myAdapter=new MyAdapter(all_users_data.this, allevent);
                yourListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

                yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(all_users_data.this,Singleitem.class);
                        intent.putExtra("name", name.getText().toString());
                        intent.putExtra("time", time.getText().toString());
                        intent.putExtra("date", date.getText().toString());
                        intent.putExtra("type", type.getText().toString());
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
```

**Singleitem.java:**

```
public class First extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editname;
    EditText edittime;
    EditText editdate;
    EditText edittype;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_singleitem);
        editname = findViewById(R.id.name);
        edittime = findViewById(R.id.time);
        editdate = findViewById(R.id.date);
        edittype = findViewById(R.id.type);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String n1 = bundle.getString("name");
        String t = bundle.getString("time");
        String d =  bundle.getString("date");
        String t1 = bundle.getString("type");
        editname.setText(n1);
        edittime.setText(t);
        editdate.setText(d);
        edittype.setText(t1);

    }
}
```